# In PHP, if 0==false is true, and false==false is true, how to test for false?

Tags: php, preg-match

I am especially interested in testing the return value of preg_match, which can be 1, 0, or false.

Answer (score 14):

```
$val === false;
```

Example:

```
0 === false; // returns false
false === false; // returns true
```

[Use triple equals operator/strict comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 6):

Use `===` type comparison.
Check the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 3):

```
$num === 0; //is true if $num is 0 and is an integer
$num === 0; //is false if $num is 0 and is a string
```

The `===` checks for type as well as equality

so:

```
 0 === false; //will return false
 false === false; //will return true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the not operator `!` to check for false: `(! 0 === false)` is always false.

Answer (score 0):

preg_match() and preg_match_all() return the number of matches found, or false in case of an error. However this means it will return 0 if no matches are found so testing explicitly for false and then trying to loop through an empty set will still be problematic.

I usually test for false, then test again for match count before looping results. Something to the effect of:

```
$match = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

if($match !== false)
{
    if(count($matches) > 0)
    {
        foreach($matches as $k=>$v)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        user_error('Sorry, no matches found');
    }
}
else
{
    die('Match error');
}
```